# Extract specific letters from text using regex and compare with dictionary

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am having a list of texts which is 90% in format **AABBB-CCCDDD001**. And there are also few texts in this list which may consist of

```
AABBBICS-CCCDDD001 or 
AABBBIGW-CCCDDD001 or 
AABBBRTL-CCCDDD001 or 
AABBBTDZ-CCCDDD001
```

These are the name of the devices where

```
AA - country code
BBB - site code
CCC - Function code
DDD - Sub Function code.
```

It could be for example: **USNYCRTL-LANDCE001**

If the code ICS, IGW, RTL or TDZ either matches with that in the text, I want it to output their respective number, for which I have created a dictionary:

```
ENVIRONMENTCODE = {
    'ICS': '1',
    'IGW': '2',
    'RTL': '3',
    'TDZ': '4'
}

NULLCODE = {
    'NULL': '9'
}
```

So, if the text is:

```
AABBBICS-CCCDDD001 it should print '1' or 
AABBBIGW-CCCDDD001 it should print '2' or 
AABBBRTL-CCCDDD001 it should print '3' or 
AABBBTDZ-CCCDDD001 it should print '4'
```

above example: **USNYCRTL-LANDCE001** should print '3' since RTL correspondes to number '3' in dictionary

Now, for the 90% of text which is in format **AABBB-CCCDDD001** should print '9' as it should pair with the key 'NULL'. Also, there maybe few texts where it can have AABBBXYZ-CCCDDD001, But we need to ignore that XYZ as it is not in the dictionary and consider only the ones that are in the dictionary. And mark that text as '9' as well.

I know regex can be used here, but I'm in the early stages of learning python and Regex seems to be out of reach for me right now. This is what I have tried so far:

```
def environmentcode(self):
    idx = self.name.find('-')
    if idx > -1:
        if self.name in ENVIRONMENTCODE:
            return ENVIRONMENTCODE
        else:
            return NULLCODE
    else:
        return "Not Found"
```

It is printing the **NULLCODE dictionary** only regardless of the keys are there in the text or not. Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.find` to get the code word, if it exists, and then use the dictionary to map the code word to its code number. We can use the dictionary `.get` method to return the null code for missing or unknown code words. This version returns `None` if it encounters bad data: a name that doesn't contain `'-'`, or a name that doesn't have either 8 or 5 letters before the `'-'`.

```
env_code = {
    'ICS': '1',
    'IGW': '2',
    'RTL': '3',
    'TDZ': '4',
}

null_code = '9'

def get_env_code(name):
    idx = name.find('-')
    if idx == 8:
        # code may be valid
        code = name[idx-3:idx]
    elif idx == 5:
        # code is missing
        code = ''
    else:
        # Bad name
        return None

    return env_code.get(code, null_code)

# test

data = [
    'AABBBICS-CCCDDD001',
    'AABBBIGW-CCCDDD001',
    'AABBBRTL-CCCDDD001',
    'AABBBTDZ-CCCDDD001',
    'USNYCRTL-LANDCE001',
    'AABBBXYZ-CCCDDD001',
    'AABBB-CCCDDD001',
    'BADDATA',
]

for s in data:
    print(s, get_env_code(s))
```

**output**

```
AABBBICS-CCCDDD001 1
AABBBIGW-CCCDDD001 2
AABBBRTL-CCCDDD001 3
AABBBTDZ-CCCDDD001 4
USNYCRTL-LANDCE001 3
AABBBXYZ-CCCDDD001 9
AABBB-CCCDDD001 9
BADDATA None
```

---

Here's a simpler version that returns the null code instead of `None` for bad data.

```
def get_env_code(name):
    idx = name.find('-')
    code = name[idx-3:idx] if idx == 8 else ''
    return env_code.get(code, null_code)
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer. 
I think it was a mistake on my part, that I forgot to mention that those codes could be lowercase or uppercase at that specific position in the text. For example, it could be either, aabbbics-cccddd001 or AABBBICS-CCCDDD001, I tried manipulating a sample text with lowercase 'ics', it couldn't read that one and extracted code '9' there.

Comment: ^ I have added lowercase codes. For example, 'ics', 'igw', 'rtl', 'tdz' in the env_code dictionary and it is working fine. Do you have any other method?

Comment: @KaranM Adding lowercase codes to the dictionary is fine. It doesn't use much more RAM, and it's fast. If the lowercase codes have the same number as the uppercase version, eg you want both 'ics' and 'ICS' to map to '1' then there's another option: you _could_ just have the uppercase codes in the dictionary and do `env_code.get(code.upper(), null_code)`. But that's actually slightly slower because it has to call `.upper()` for every code.

Comment: Okay, So i have added those lowercase codes to my dictionary and it's working all fine! Btw, I have finished my whole code today and it's unbelievably 170-odd lines of script. This is quite shocking yet mesmerizing for someone who is just 2 months old in Python. If you are up for it, shall we look into it and try to optimize the code, because I feel this would be adding to much to the RAM. I am already trying it, but would be really glad if I have a mentor with me , cause I am trying my best at it.

Comment: @KaranM Questions asking to optimize complete working programs are generally off-topic on Stack Overflow. They are acceptable on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), although they have strict rules there, so you need to read those rules carefully before posting. However, it's possible to get some help with optimization on SO by focusing on a single section of your program that you believe could be sped up or use less RAM. So you need to create a [MCVE] of that section, explain what it does, and why you think it could be improved.

Comment: Got it! I'll try my best. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Hi! I was just figuring out this function in my code and I couldn't  understand the logic you have used here. Can you please explain why idx == 8 and idx == 5. I lose myself when I'm trying to understand this function. Please help!

Comment: @KaranM My code is designed to process names that have the format that you show in the question. If a name is valid then either the '_' is at index 8 for names of the format `'AABBBICS-CCCDDD001'`, or it's at index 5 for names of the format `'AABBB-CCCDDD001'`. If there are valid names that aren't in those two formats then you should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: It is running perfectly fine. Although, there can be environment code longer than 3 letters, but they don't matter because in the end they will be referenced to null_code only.  So I changed 'return None' to 'return null_code' for bad name and it is working well. I just wanted to know the logic you used because I forgot to ask this when you gave the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

If you're just checking if a member of `ENVIRONMENTCODE` is found within each test string, then regex not necessary. You can just use the python keyword `in`, e.g.

```
ENVIRONMENTCODE = {
    'ICS': '1',
    'IGW': '2',
    'RTL': '3',
    'TDZ': '4'
}

NULLCODE = {
    'NULL': '9'
}

def environment_code(test_string, code_dict):
    if '-' not in test_string:
        return 'no dash'
    for code, value in code_dict.items():
        if code in test_string:
            return value
    return NULLCODE['NULL']


to_test = ['AABBBICS-CCCDDD001',
           'AABBBIGW-CCCDDD001',
           'AABBBRTL-CCCDDD001',
           'AABBBTDZ-CCCDDD001']
for test_str in to_test:
    print(environment_code(test_str, ENVIRONMENTCODE))
```

The problem with your original code was that you were trying to do

`test_string in code_dict`

which only checks for exact matches between the string under test and the keys withint the dictionary.

Comment: There are lots of devices with name ICS, IGW, RTL or TDZ in the text. I wont be able to create a to_test dictionary there. I got to match only that 3 specific letters at those position and if it matches print out their respective number code. Got it?

Comment: @KaranM In that case your sample data of `AABBBICS-CCCDDD001` etc is a bit misleading. Perhaps you should add some more strings to show us what the data really looks like.

Comment: The to_test list is only as an example. You should just just call the function environment_code() above on each device name you have

Answer (score 0):

My proposal:

```
def environmentcode(s):
    if "-" not in s:  #(**)
        return None   #(**)
    h,t=s.split("-")
    code=h.strip()[5:]
    return ENVIRONMENTCODE.get(code,9)   

data="AABBBICS-CCCDDD001 AABBBIGW-CCCDDD001 AABBBRTL-CCCDDD001 AABBBTDZ-CCCDDD001 USNYCRTL-LANDCE001 AABBB-CCCDDD001 something"

for s in data.split():
    print(s,"-->",environmentcode(s))

Output:
AABBBICS-CCCDDD001 --> 1
AABBBIGW-CCCDDD001 --> 2
AABBBRTL-CCCDDD001 --> 3
AABBBTDZ-CCCDDD001 --> 4
USNYCRTL-LANDCE001 --> 3
AABBB-CCCDDD001 --> 9
something --> None

#---------------------------------------------------------
# Filtering text with regex. In this case, (**) not needed.
text="""AABBBICS-CCCDDD001 Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank... AABBBIGW-CCCDDD001 AABBBRTL-CCCDDD001 AABBBTDZ-CCCDDD001 USNYCRTL-LANDCE001 AABBB-CCCDDD001 AABBBXYZ-CCCDDD001 something"""

import re

data= re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]{5,8}-[A-Z]{6}001\b",text)
for s in data:
    print(s,"-->",environmentcode(s))
```

Comment: This is the format that I showed above and there could be any characters in those texts in between the 'ICS', 'IGW', 'RTL', 'TDZ'. We have to check for these codes in the text at that specific position only. if it does not have any text at that position or if it has some other code at that position then return a NULL code, that is, number 9