# Check if string qualifies to extract text from the string - Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am new to regex, and I don't have just a string to extract the desired text but, I also need to allow other type of strings that don't match the regex to iterate in my other functions.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

I am running through device names from a csv file, If it has only DeviceName without the string mentioned below, it should simply return that to the function and let other function take care of it.
The string where I want to use regex will be like

'Card ADFGTR43567 on "DeviceName"' where I want to extract only the **DeviceName** from it.

**ADFGTR43567** is a serial number and there are 11 letters in it, consisting of numbers and alphabets with no definite positions.

Here DeviceName could be anything, for EX: it could be ARIEFRETO002 or ARIERDTOT5968.na.abc.com or even just a plain mac address like 1234.abcd.5678
So even if the string has a pattern like 'Card serialnumber on DeviceName'.

I would want it to extract DeviceName and run against other functions in my code. If the device name in my csv is without such pattern, I would still want it to extract them and give it to the other function.

I have written a code with my functions, but I am not able to use regex here. This is what I have tried so far, only pasting the necessary info.

```
def validnames():
    idx = col[0].find('-')
    if idx > -1:
        user = col[0][idx + 1:idx + 4]
        if user.upper() in d:
            return col[0].split('.')[0]
        else:
            return 'Not Found'
    else:
        return 'Not Found'


def pingable():
    response = subprocess.Popen(['ping.exe', validnames()], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    response = response.decode()
    if 'bytes=32' in response:
        status = 'Up'
        return status
    else:
        status = 'Down'
        return status

with open("Book2.csv", 'r') as lookuplist:
    for col in csv.reader(lookuplist):
        if validnames() == 'Not Found' : continue
        if pingable() == 'Down' : continue
        if validnames().lower() not in data:
            with open('Test.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvoutput:
                output = csv.writer(csvoutput)
                output.writerows([[validnames()]+[pingable()]])
                print("Device: %s" % validnames(), pingable())
```

`def validnames():` is a function to check if that device is eligible for the ping operation (based on the condition). I was thinking to put regex in that function, and I got lost there completely!) Maybe another function, but not quite getting how to do with regex.

UPDATE: This is how I have integrated two functions, based on the accepted answer.

```
def regexfilter():
        try:
            rx = r'\bon\s+(\S+)'
            m = re.search(rx, col[0])
            if m:
                return m.group(1)
            else:
                return col[0]
        except:
            return col[0]


def validnames():
    idx = regexfilter().find('-')
    if idx > -1:
        user = regexfilter()[idx + 1:idx + 4]
        if user.upper() in d:
            return regexfilter().split('.')[0]
        else:
            return 'Not Found'
    else:
        return 'Not Found'
```

Comment: Please be clear regarding what the regex should match and what it should not. You said 11 characters but `1234.abcd.5678` has 14. "could be anything" also doesn't really help much...

Comment: It's not clear, Explain with two three examples.

Comment: but why dont use split functiond to do that?

Comment: @DeepSpace, I was thinking, if we can extract any type of text after the word `on` and whitespace i.e, `Card AERTO8765WE on DeviceName` Just get the DeviceName

Comment: @KaranM `r'.*on\s(.*)'`  will match whatever comes after `on `, but it may be too much. Unless we know what comes after the device name it would be impossible to tell. Be aware that `\s` also matches a new line. If you want an explicit whitespace, use `r'.*on (.*)'`.

Comment: @DeepSpace, Maybe if I try to filter only those texts which has `Card` in it initially and then use regex on them? Will that work?

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\bon\s+(\S+)', s)` or, if the DeviceName is always in double quotes,  `re.findall(r'\bon\s+"([^"]+)"', s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to match any text inside double quotation marks that follows an `on` preposition, you may use the following regex:

```
\bon\s+(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C3rBJL/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `on` - `on` word
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xLR1iJ):

```
import re
rx = r'\bon\s+(\S+)'
s = "Card ADFGTR43567 on DeviceName"
m = re.search(rx, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => DeviceName
```

Comment: This worked!! thank you so much. Although, this answer shows only the Regex operation, but I have to return also the text that doesn't have this pattern. I have just added try and except to it and returned col[0]. I am accepting the answer as it gave me the logic. Although, I'll edit my post and paste my code that is working, please have a look at it and let me know if I can change anything in the regex operation, the code is taking too long during execution i think.

Comment: @KaranM You do not need `try...except` in `def regexfilter()`. What are you doing in `def validnames()`?

Comment: I am extracting those 3 letters from the device name at that fixed position, called as function codes and depending on them I have to query further operations.

Comment: @KaranM I could try and help you better, but there are too many unknowns for me in your code. Please explain the format of the match. `\S+` just matches 1+ non-whitespace chars, but you are looking for `-` and `.` there, why?

Comment: Just to save some space [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312285/extract-specific-letters-from-text-using-regex-and-compare-with-dictionary), I'd really appreciate if you can give a look to my question here which explains the data format of the device. All the conditions remain same, but we are looking to extract `CCC` part, i.e, Function Codes

Comment: @KaranM Sorry, I still have no idea what exactly the data looks like. I have come to https://ideone.com/1gM43X, but no idea what `d` is and why you are trying to get a substring till the first `.`,  if it is expected, you should specify the format of the expected matches more precisely.

Comment: @KaranM Hints: 1) Do not repeat `regexfilter()`, assign its result to a variable and re-use it. 2) `re.compile` the regex and use a compiled version. 3) You may use *captures*, enclose parts of regex with `(...)` and you will be able to access them with `m.group(1)`, `m.group(2)`, etc.